# Django getting SMTP Server URL as URL in the password reset email

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I made a Django application with custom users.

I followed the docs to create my password reset pages and forms. I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812985/django-password-reset-email-subject-line-contains-example-com) and tweaked my configuration to use the right domain name. My `SITE_ID` is set to 1, and I'm sure the `Site` with `pk=1` is configured to be my domain.

When I try to get a password reset email, the subject contains the correct URL for the site I am requesting the password reset for. (Subject is "Password reset for myMainDomain.com")

The problem is the link inside the mail: the auto-generated link points to a CNAME of my **mailserver**, for some unknown reason. Django shouldn't even know that, since the only place I put the mailserver's domain is in the mail settings in  `setting.py`

My `users.urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
                path('', views.UserListView.as_view(), name='lista-user'),
                path('accounts/signup/', views.Iscriviti.as_view(), name='signup'),
                path('<int:pk>', views.Profilo.as_view(), name='profilo'),
                path('accounts/edit/<int:pk>', views.Modifica.as_view(), name='modifica-utente')]
```

My template `password_reset_email.html`:

```
Here is your password-reset link:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

Relevant part of my `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.myMailServerdomain.it'
EMAIL_PORT = '25'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MYUSER'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MYPASS'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply@myMailServerdomain.it'

SITE_ID = 1 # -> This is the site I configured on Django, with my_site.domain = 'myMainDomain.com' and my_site.name = 'My site's name'
```

The email I get when I try a password reset:

```
Here is your password-reset link:
http://tracking.mymailserverdomain.it/f3ag34/Go6CyRfZ=0D
```

`tracking.mymailserverdomain.it` is a CNAME of my domain `mymailserverdomain.it` which I pointed to `track.mail.mymailserverdomain.it`. I tried to send an empty mail with `{{domain}}` inside to see if my SMTP server used that for some reason, but it doesn't and just puts `{{domain}}` in the mail.

How can I investigate this behavior?

Comment: Are you using the generic Password Reset views or are you using a custom view? Can you include the view your using in the post?

Comment: I am using the generic password reset view, all I did was adding
`path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')`
to my urlpatterns and overwrite the views just for the ones you see above

`

Comment: Oh my bad, must've missed that. That is strange. You might have to overwrite the PasswordResetView to figure out what it's doing. Normally it should get the proper domain from the request

Comment: I now solved the issue by overriding the view completely. Now it uses a custom email template with the base url hardcoded in it, it's not elegant at all but it works.
I'm just wondering how in the world Django got that name, it is hosted on a completely different server with a different domain. Still, if I put it on default configuration, it uses the mailserver's CNAME domain as a hostname in reset email.